# sensors reports negative CPU temperature for Ryzen

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

`sensors` used to work well for me but since upgrading to a Ryzen 2700X the readings don't make sense.

```
nct6779-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                  +0.56 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                    +1.27 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:                   +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                  +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                    +1.84 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                    +0.82 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                    +1.20 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                   +3.46 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                   +3.26 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                    +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in10:                   +0.83 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                   +1.09 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                   +1.69 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                   +0.93 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                   +1.82 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                   932 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  2351 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                   992 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                   918 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +33.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 -62.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +15.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                +35.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                +21.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                -25.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C
PCH_MCH_TEMP:            +0.0°C
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +92.9°C  (high = +70.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A
```

Where is my CPU temperature in here? What's with all the `ALARM`s? Why is `CPUTIN` -62C? What is the `temp1` that is reporting 93C? I'm pretty sure my system is neither supercooled nor overheating. BIOS reports CPU temp at around 30-40C, the output above was with <5% average CPU usage, nothing significant running, so shouldn't be much higher.

I just want to get a CPU temperature out of this so I can put it in my conky.